# Length of the factorial

Tags: python-3.x

I tried running the program below:

```
from functools import lru_cache
@lru_cache(Maxsize = None)

def count(n):
    factorial_num = 1
    num_digits = 0
    if n == 1:
       factorial_num = 1
    else:
        factorial_num = n * count(n-1)
    return len(str(factorial_num))
```

However, it didn't give me the length of the factorial number as anticipated.

I also wanted to use the code to find the factorial of very big numbers in range of billions and tried using `lru_cache`. Still, no luck.

Comment: You're doing two things at once: computing the factorial, and finding its length. The problem is that they are both done inside the recursive function, so every recursive call is returning the length. You should compute the factorial separately, then get the length of the result.

Comment: However, when I only try to print the factorial number, it prints. Why can't the length be printed?@Aziz Help me out

Comment: Compute the factorial first, then find the length separately (outside this function).

Comment: @Aziz. I did. However, it displayed the wrong output.I have to return the length of the factorial in the given function.

Comment: Can you update your question and show an example of the wrong output you're getting?

Comment: I get 3 for factorial of 50 and 4 for factorial for 500.

Comment: Recursion is a bad fit for computing large factorials, even with memorization/caching.  A basic loop will be much more efficient, and not subject to recursion depth limitations.

Answer (score 1):

As Aziz pointed out in the comments, your recursive case is wrong.

```
factorial_num = n * count(n-1)
```

This would do something useful if `count(n-1)` actually returned (n-1)!, but it doesn't, since you're trying to return a digit count instead.

```
>>> count(1)
1    # Base case is correct.
>>> count(2)
1    # 2 * count(1) = 2 * 1 = 2.  Whose *length* is 1 digit.
>>> count(9)
1    # For all single-digit n, count(n) is still 1.
>>> count(10)
2    # 10 * count(9) = 10 * 1 = 10.  Whose *length* is 2 digits.
```

You should write a function that *just* calculates the factorial, instead of trying to mix this logic with the digit counting.

```
@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n - 1)
```

Note that recent versions of Python have a built-in `math.factorial` function, which you could use instead if your teacher is not requiring you to roll your own factorial code.

Then, you can simply use `len(str(factorial(n)))` to count the digits.

Comment: @Aziz thanks for the help. the only way to use cache memory I know is lru_cache and it doesn't work for numbers like 50000000. Still stuck in it.

Comment: @Aziz. Basic loop gave me run time error. That's why I was trying cache storage.

Comment: @AnmolGautam Is there some reason you need to know the value of `50000000!`? That's such a stupendously huge number that I can't imagine any real application for it.

Comment: @AnmolGautam: My `factorial` function as written requires a recursive call for every value from `n` down to the current maximum cached value.  If you happen to have previously calculated `factorial(49999999)`, then it would work just fine.  But starting from scratch, that's 50 million recursive calls.

Comment: @dan04 the question I am doing calculates the number like 50,500,5000 and so on upto 500000.

Comment: Do you need the *exact* value?  When you have numbers that large, Stirling's approximation would be faster.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh This is a question on algorithm and I am just doing some questions to get comfortable for memoization and dynamic programming.

Comment: @dan04. I need the length. I believe it might be approximate as well. For eg, the answer of 50000000   is    363233781.

Comment: @AnmolGautam: For numbers this huge, it may be faster to work with logarithms.  Recall that log(n!) = log(1*2*3*...*n) = log(1)+log(2)+log(3)+...+log(n).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Kamenetsky formula to return the number of digits in n!

For minor numbers use:

```
def findDigits(n): 

    if (n < 0): 
        return 0; 

    if (n <= 1): 
        return 1; 

    digits = 0; 
    for i in range(2, n + 1): 
        digits += math.log10(i); 

    return math.floor(digits) + 1;
```

For bigger numbers use:

```
def findDigits(n): 

    if (n < 0): 
        return 0; 

    if (n <= 1): 
        return 1; 

    x = ((n * math.log10(n / math.e) + 
              math.log10(2 * math.pi * n) /2.0)); 

    return math.floor(x) + 1;
```

source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-digits-factorial-set-1/?ref=lbp and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-digits-factorial-set-2/?ref=lbp